# ElasticSearch _search query to bring filtered and nested documents

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, nested, documents

I have the following document type:

```
"_source": {
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "surname": "abcdn",
    "custom_attributes": {
        "custom1": "2bdwfwefgwef",
        "custom2": "2015-08-03 00:43:00",
        "custom3": "United States (English)"
    },
    "language": "US",
    "gender": "m"
    }
```

I want to **filter** by **name** and **surname** and also bring it's nested elements **without** filtering(in this case it is "custom_attributes")

Here's the query I'm using;

```
{
  "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
  "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "and" : [
               {"missing" : { "field" : "name" } },
               {"missing" : { "field" : "surname" } }
            ]
         }
        }
      }
}
```

But the problem is that it doesn't bring the child elements(it comes as empty Map() and I couldnt figure out how to use the "nested" notation here to bring the custom_attributes

Comment: Could you provide a result example? You should get the sub-document even without mapping it as nested.

Comment: can you provide the mapping you use?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `bool` query. I've tried with the following simple example (and dynamic mapping):

```
POST my_index/my_type/
{
  "name": "a",
  "surname": "a",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "custom_attributes": {
    "custom1": "2bdwfwefgwef",
    "custom2": "2015-08-03 00:43:00",
    "custom3": "United States (English)"
  },
  "language": "US",
  "gender": "m"
}
POST my_index/my_type/
{
  "name": "b",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "custom_attributes": {
    "custom1": "2bdwfwefgwef",
    "custom2": "2015-08-03 00:43:00",
    "custom3": "United States (English)"
  },
  "language": "US",
  "gender": "m"
}
POST my_index/my_type/
{
  "surname": "c",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "custom_attributes": {
    "custom1": "2bdwfwefgwef",
    "custom2": "2015-08-03 00:43:00",
    "custom3": "United States (English)"
  },
  "language": "US",
  "gender": "m"
}
POST my_index/my_type/
{
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "custom_attributes": {
    "custom1": "2bdwfwefgwef",
    "custom2": "2015-08-03 00:43:00",
    "custom3": "United States (English)"
  },
  "language": "US",
  "gender": "m"
}
GET my_index/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "name"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "surname"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which results in:

```
{
  "took": 51,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "AVmfDTiBdjT9iO0jiYdN",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "email": "abc@gmail.com",
          "custom_attributes": {
            "custom1": "2bdwfwefgwef",
            "custom2": "2015-08-03 00:43:00",
            "custom3": "United States (English)"
          },
          "language": "US",
          "gender": "m"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: it should be "filter": {
            "and" : [
               {"missing" : { "field" : "name" } },
               {"missing" : { "field" : "surname" } }
            ]
         }

Comment: Ok, I've fixed my answer. What you're looking for is an `exists` in a `must_not`.